# Why this warning "warning: assignment to 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)[3]'"?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

If array name points to the first element , then n should give location of 2,
why this warning is there then?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n[3][3] = {
        {2,4,3},
        {6,8,5},
        {3,5,1}
      };
      int i ,*pt;
      pt = n ;
     
      for (int i = 0; i <=8; i++)
      {
        printf("%d\n",*(pt + i) );
      }
}
```

But when I write `pt = *n`; it works just fine. Why??

Comment: `*(pt + i)` is equivalent to `pt[i]`. Since `pt` is a 2-dimensional array, `pt[i]` is a row of the array, not a single `int`.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays.

Comment: I suggest a read through section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: because the first element of n is not an int, it is an array of 3 ints.

Comment: If you want just a plain `int *` to the first element use `pt = &n[0][0];` instead. It is (equivalent to, but) a lot more readable than `pt = *n;`.

Comment: If it is array of 3 ints , still then the first element stored in memeory is 2 , so location of 2 shouldn't be returned then?

Comment: Yes, the address of the array of 3 ints is the same as the address of the first element of the array (2). That is why it works. But it is still weird for the compiler !

Answer (score 0):

In certain contexts, an array type will "decay" into a pointer type, where
the outer array dimension `[]` is replaced with `*`.  For example, `int a[5]` will decay to `int *`, and `int b[5][10]` will decay to `int (*)[10]`.

In your case, `int n[3][3]` decays to `int (*)[3]`, so you could assign `n` to a pointer of that type with no need for a cast.  But it is incompatible with an `int *`, such as `int *pt`, so attempting to assign `n` to `pt` results in an error.  You could instead declare `int (*pt)[3];` if you wanted `pt` to be a compatible pointer type.

If you want to treat `n` as flat storage, and access it with `int *pt;`, you could cast it to `int *`, as in `pt = (int *) n;`.  In this case you would be able to treat `n` as a flat array of `9` integers.  You could then reference the elements with `pt[i]`, which is the normal way one would write the equivalent `*(pt + i)`.

Usually one tries to use compatible pointer types, without the need to cast, when possible.  But if you really want to treat the array as having a different shape, then you can use a cast when doing the pointer assignment, provided the data layouts are compatible.